# How to open an evolution compose window with file attachment

Tags: email, evolution

In order to (semi-)automate some of my workflows I would like to find a way to open an Evolution mail compose window with a file of my choosing already attached.

I have learned so far that:

- Evolution accepts "mailto:" links at the command line, but unfortunately the "mailto:" URL scheme does not allow specifying an attachment.
- the functionality for opening a compose window with a file already attached is exposed by  Evolution in some fashion, since I can select "Send to..." from the context menu for a file  in Nautilus and an Evolution mail compose window with that file attached will pop up.

My attempts to find out how I could achieve this myself were thwarted by either lack of documentation or my inability to come up with the right search terms. Anything from an out-of-the-box-solution from someone who already solved that problem before me to a pointer to the documentation to an API (dbus, most likely?) that allows me to achieve my goal are viable options for me, so *any* pointer short of "take a look at the nautilus code and see how they do it" (which is my Plan C) would be greatly appreciated.

Also, suggesting a different mail client that more readily exposes the desired functionality is unlikely to help me, unless said mail client supports Office 365 "modern authentication" which, to the best of my knowledge, only Evolution does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through a stroke of luck I stumbled across the answer myself, with evolution as the default mail application I can simply use

```
xdg-email --attach <filename>
```

and it will do precisely what I was trying to do.

It is part of xdg-utils and came preinstalled on Ubuntu 20.10 and seeing that it is a freedesktop package should be available for most distributions.

I then ended up going deeper into the rabbit hole just to learn that evolution in fact **does** support attachment for mailto: links like this

```
evolution mailto:\?attach=<filename>
```

Whether or not you need the backslash depends on your shell and calling context.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are talking about is called `"Attended Automation"` process, This as per my understanding to your problem, the easiest way may be achieved by automating the process you asked through `Selenium`.

This [doc](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/introduction/on_test_automation/) may explain more.

Also this [article](https://www.thinkautomation.com/eli5/whats-the-difference-between-attended-and-unattended-bots/) will explain the difference between attended and unattended automations.

Comment: No, that's not it. Selenium is for web and Evolution is a desktop app.

Comment: If your application has a web/online version, then you can use it.